# JMeter: Script in VM Vs Azure Pipeline

Tags: jmeter, azure-devops, cicd, jenkins-pipeline

Testing web based application for Performance Testing. Servers are physical servers.
Script is running without errors in vm and in vm by using Host Entry files is to pointing out to PREUAT Enviornment.

Same script pushed into Azure Pipeline but getting as **Non HTTP response code: java.net.UnknownHostException/Non HTTP response message: aviarywebui.com    40  83.33%  83.33%
Non HTTP response code: java.net.UnknownHostException/Non HTTP response message: aviarywebidentity.com **

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

JMeter script [![enter image description here][2]][2]
[![enter image description here][3]][3]
[![enter image description here][4]][4]

In the Azure Pipeline logs shows as succeeded.

[![enter image description here][5]][5]

[![enter image description here][6]][6]

[![enter image description here][7]][7]

[![enter image description here][8]][8]

[![enter image description here][9]][9]

[![enter image description here][10]][10]

[![enter image description here][11]][11]

[![enter image description here][12]][12]

Could anyone please help me
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Gjll.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pbj2B.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jUao.png
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wk4B0.png
[5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wfnjm.png
[6]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWxS2.png
[7]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tI3n6.png
[8]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/39wfi.png
[9]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpTxt.png
[10]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPRiT.png
[11]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ah9b.png
[12]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hcr9V.png

Answer (score 0):

The error means that JMeter's HTTP Request samplers cannot reach https://aviarywebui.com host.

I cannot access it as well:

[image]

and [it's not only me](https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/aviarywebui.com?proto=https):

[image]

- So if the website requires a VPN connection - you need to install VPN client onto Azure runner machine first and connect to the VPN before starting the test.
- If the website is accessible via HTTP Proxy - specify the proxy in [HTTP Requests Defaults](https://guides.blazemeter.com/g/new-blazemeter-guide-311365/23622)

  [image]
- If the website doesn't have public DNS hostname but accessible via IP address you can add DNS Cache Manager to your test plan and specify the IP address there

  [image]